# How to add Images inside a custom container on Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I want to add images to Mapbox in a similar style as follow:

[image: GasBuddy App]

I am not sure how to go about doing this since Mapbox doesn't really offer many options when adding an image to the map. I have tried adding a custom marker with an image inside it and that works but then I lose layer features such as hiding etc. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image and then use it as part of a symbol layer. You can see it in one of the [official examples](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/).

```js
    map.on('load', function () {
        map.loadImage(
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/201408_cat.png',
            function (error, image) {
                if (error) throw error;
                map.addImage('cat', image);
                map.addSource('point', {
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                        'features': [
                            {
                                'type': 'Feature',
                                'geometry': {
                                    'type': 'Point',
                                    'coordinates': [0, 0]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'points',
                    'type': 'symbol',
                    'source': 'point',
                    'layout': {
                        'icon-image': 'cat',
                        'icon-size': 0.25
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: This way there will be only ONE image on the map? What if we need to add an IMAGE per feature? For instance, I want to add an arrow to each dynamically created `LineString`, at its last coordinate position... I'd prefer to have this arrow as a part of `LineString` feature (so I would be able to delete it once its `LineString` is deleted or move it together with the `LineString`) instead of creating tons of new layers and handling them somehow separately...

Comment: That’s a different question. I’d suggest you to submit a new question

Comment: Already ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313705/how-to-make-a-mapbox-line-tip-as-an-arrow-not-as-a-separate-layer

Answer (score 0):

In order to add multiple images in mapbox you can use the same loadImage and addImage multiple times. My advice would be to keep the images in an array and then iterate over them and just do loadImage part.

```
const images = [{url: <IMage1_URL>, name: <Image1_Name>}, {url: <IMage2_URL>, name: <Image2_Name>}]
images.forEach(img => {
  map.loadImage(
    img.url,
    function (error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      map.addImage(img.name, image);
    }
})
```

On the other hand if you want to draw a custom svg like maybe just a blue icon or something very specific using d3.js/canvas. I've used canvas in the past and might be able to create a minimalist demo for ya if you need it.

There's another way to do it but it'll require you to add the markers explicitly on the map but you can have something like DonutChart as well on the map and that looks quite good!. Here's the link to that [blog](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster-html/).

Thanks!